# Handle the click of Navigation drawer Hamburger icon when FAB button is open

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, floating-action-button

I have a navigation drawer layout in my fragment and a floating action menu in the layout. Now when the floating action menu expands then i have to handle the click of the navigation drawer hamburger icon.

When floating action menu expands then the navigation icon should not work and don't allow drawer to open.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
    break;
    }
```

I have tried this but, it isn't working.
If someone has a better answer that is useful please let me know.

Comment: do you fixed it ??

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan not yet..

Comment: so you want to disable your navigation drawer when fab menu is open. correct ?

Comment: do the fab menu lies in the same layout where the drawer layout is present ???

Comment: Fab icon is present in one of the fragment of my navigation drawer.